# This app has been removed from Google Play for violating the Google Play Developer Program Policies. Android App rejection

Tags: android

After review,  has been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.

Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Console, and from within the app.

Next steps: Submit your app for another review

```
Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User Data policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and make appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect sensitive user information, be sure to abide by the above policies, and include a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app. 
Make sure that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.
Sign in to your Play Console and submit the update to your app.
```

Alternatively, you may opt-out of this requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user data.

If approved, your app will again be available with all installs, ratings, and reviews intact.

If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this removal may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.

Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for Google Play users.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Create the privacy policy for your app - you can use [this policy generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/)
2. Put it on your web.
3. Then go to play store console -> Store presence -> App content -> find field Privacy Policy and provide an url with this policy there.
4. Send update
5. Profit

Comment: Same case but there  is not privacy policy field in store listing .What should I do

Comment: No privacy policy field

Comment: You can find privacy policy in following path.
Store Presence > App content -> Privacy policy

Comment: how long does it to be available on the store again. for my case it was  the long description, I fixed it and a button submit app appeared. I clicked it and im still waiting , it's been two days .

Comment: After new update policy section is there in bottom separate section

Comment: Just updating the privacy policy will be enough? or do we need create new release with new build after policy update?

Answer (score 0):

**Here I got the error in play console.**

[image]

Step 1 : Check the Data form filled up on Right way.

Step 2: Add Privacy policy link(If not available then make dummy policy on web) and mandatory links which needed.

Step 3 : Check if App need access from ID and password then include dummy id and password in **App Content.**

[image]

**Now, Post this app in Review after Here add User Name and his Id and Password. All Done.**